# Reset styling after entity insert with Draft.js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am inserting some entity in `Draft.js` (just some styled immutable text):

```
contentState = Modifier.insertText(
            contentState,
            selectionState,
            '{{1}}',
            OrderedSet.of('PLACEHOLDER_COLOR'),
            entityKey
        );
```

The problem is that, after I insert it, if I try to continue typing style will be like that inserted entity. I want style to be like it was before I inserted that entity - can I reset it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use `setInlineStyleOverride` to set inline style for next input character. Also please to known the `DefatInlineStyle` is just a `OrderedSet<string>`.